# How do I get the string at stopped label?

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I am using iCarosuel and I have a populated array, and it is displayed, but when I scroll and stop on a value, I want that value to be printed. Whatever value the scroller stops on, print that value.

```
   func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var labels: UILabel
    var itemView: UIImageView

    if(view == nil){
        itemView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:400, height:100))
        itemView.image = UIImage(named: "page")
        itemView.contentMode = .Center

        labels = UILabel(frame: itemView.bounds)
        labels.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        labelsubject.textAlignment = .Center
        labels.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        labels.tag = 1
        itemView.addSubview(labels)

    }else{
        itemView = view as! UIImageView;
        labels = itemView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel!

    }
    labels.text = "\(text[index])"

    return itemView
}
```

Comment: Never used iCarosuel but I think there is definately a way to get it's index. And you should set your text using  `labels.text = textForIndex(index)` so you can get that text later by calling textForIndex with index.

Answer (score 0):

```
func carouselDidEndDragging(carousel: iCarousel, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    if !decelerate {
        print(carousel.currentItemIndex)
        //text[carousel.currentItemIndex]
    }
}

func carouselDidEndDecelerating(carousel: iCarousel) {
    print(carousel.currentItemIndex)
    //text[carousel.currentItemIndex]
}
```